# Cygwin Icon Broken to Terminal Only

Tags: cygwin

I have had Cygwin installed to my Win10 Home PC for about a year, recently the icon for the Cygwin terminal went bad when accessed from the context menu:

**>>Right-Click of Context Menu Selection** (*icon missing?*)

[image: Cygwin64 from right-click menu selection]

The icon looks correct on the application file (*mintty.exe*), in the Start menu shortcut, in the context menu listing and even the Cygwin terminal when opened from the start menu -

**>>Start Menu Selection** (*icon correct*)

[image: Cygwin64 from start menu]

I have enabled the context menu selection with the "Icon" string value as follows:

- **Location #1:** HKCR\Drive\shell\cygwin64_bash

[image: HKCR\Drive\shell\cygwin64_bash]

- **Loc:** HKCR\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin64_bash

[image: HKCR\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin64_bash]

- **Loc:** HKCR\Directory\shell\cygwin64_bash

[image: HKCR\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin64_bash]

- **Value:** *"D:\Documents\MyMedia\MyIcons\sw\Cygwin\cygwin_logo.ico"*

[image: File confirmation]

What is the issue here, how can I get context menu's terminal icon restored?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of that context menu entry in Registry Editor? Did you add that registry manually? Cygwin installer doesn't add context menu.

Comment: Hi @Biswapriyo, I have added these pictures for reference, thank you for the request

Answer (score 0):

Got it, this one was simple! I had been calling 'bash.exe', not 'mintty.exe'. Changing this in the command key quickly resolved the problem -

[image]

Neat! Note that mintty.exe has an icon on my computer, while bash.exe does not, so the observed behavior was expected.

**Useful Resources**

- [Stack Overflow - Windows Cygwin Bash.exe vs. mintty.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031164/cygwin-bash-exe-vs-mintty-exe)
- [How-ToGeek - How to Modify the Icon of an EXE File](https://www.howtogeek.com/75983/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-modify-the-icon-of-an-.exe-file/)